# Simple Binding of Data from code behind to XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, xaml

I am new to WPF concepts. I want to just display a string in a textbox. I tried the following C# code and XAML to bind a string to a TextBox.Text property.
C# code:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public int TmpVal;
    public string TmpStr;

     public Window1()
    {
        TmpVal = 50;
        TmpStr = "Windows Created";
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }
    private void viewButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
    {
        TmpStr = "Button clicked";
    }
}
```

}

XAML:

```
 <Window x:Class="TestWPF.Window1"
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="Window1" Height="600" Width="800" x:Name="ThisWindow">
<Grid>
    <TextBox Name="txtTest1" Margin="200,0,200,200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" Width="200" Text="{Binding TmpStr, ElementName=ThisWindow}" />
    <Button Name="butTest1"  Click="viewButton_Click">Test123</Button>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

On execution I always get blank text in my textbox (even when I invoke the click event).

 I browsed through the stackoverflow site but couldn't solve the problem (though many questions were close to this one)

 Can someone suggest me if anything is overlooked or missed out?

Answer (score 5):

Databinding does not work with fields. Use Properties instead:

```
public int TmpVal {get; set;}
public string TmpStr {get; set;}
```

Also if you want the textbox to automatically pick up changes from your data you would ideally need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged or make it a dependency property <strike>or have a XXXChanged event for each XXX property</strike> (*this doesn't work anymore*).

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication5.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300" x:Name="ThisWindow">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Name="txtTest1" Text="{Binding TmpStr, ElementName=ThisWindow}" />
        <Button Name="butTest1"  Click="viewButton_Click">Test123</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

And the code behind:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Window1()
    {
        this.TmpStr = "Windows Created";
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string TmpStr { get; set; }

    public int TmpVal { get; set; }

    private void viewButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
    {
        this.TmpStr = "Button clicked";
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("TmpStr"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why XXXChanged events doesn't work anymore? Where can I read about this?

Comment: I think is was only there in some CTPs or early betas of v1.

Comment: You should implement the `PropertyChanged` code in the Property Setter. Thus if your property gets changed by code the UI will update.

Comment: I took this for granted. I just wanted to display as little code as possible.

Comment: THANK YOU! "Databinding does not work with fields. Use Properties instead"