# Link between INotifyPropertyChanged and Databinding

Tags: wpf, silverlight

I read this

[Simple Binding of Data from code behind to XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687070/simple-binding-of-data-from-code-behind-to-xaml)

What's the link between INotifyPropertyChanged and Databinding above not clear from the sample code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to review [Data Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278072%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) in the MSDN documentation for a more clear description of how data binding is working in Silverlight and WPF. When you define a data binding declaratively in XAML, an instance of the [Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) class is created that connects the properties of binding targets and data sources. It is this Binding class that is performing the monitoring and propagation of changes between the target of the binding and the data source.

While it is technically possible to bind to CLR objects that do not implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface, it is definitely recommended that "for changes to the source object to propagate to the target, the source must implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface. INotifyPropertyChanged has the PropertyChanged event, which tells the **binding engine** that the source has changed so that the binding engine can update the target value." See [How Data Binding References are Resolved](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613546.aspx#HowDataBindingReferencesAreResolved) for further details.

Comment: thanks that's what I wanted http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613546.aspx#HowDataBindingReferencesAreResolved

Answer (score 1):

if you have a piece of code that needs to update the UI and the UI is bound to a Poperty like in that example, INotifyPropertyChanged is how we can update the UI without having to do anything extra.

Comment: Yes that I know but in the code above what happens when INotifyPropertyChanged raise the event ?

Answer (score 1):

When you bind your property in xaml (XP) to property in code (CP), the binding contains link to object, which contains CP and the name of CP. If the object inherits INotifyPropertyChanged, binding system subscribes on PropertyChanged event and every single time it rises, binding system receives property-name string from propertyChangedEventArgs object and updates bindings for all XPs which are binded to CP with that name.