# WPF Data binding C# in xaml

Tags: class, xaml, data-binding

I would like to make the following code to be XAML:

```C#
CData cData = new CData();

MyClass mc1 = new MyClass();
MyClass mc2 = new MyClass();

mc1.Data = cData;
mc2.Data = cData;
```

How to make the above code to be XAML format?
Since the property .Data is a custom class `CData` and Both `mc1` and `mc3` has to point to the same `cData`. How to make it in XAML?

Comment: might the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687070/simple-binding-of-data-from-code-behind-to-xaml  will help full for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:CData x:Key="CData"/>
    <local:MyClass x:Key="mc1" Data="{StaticResource CData}" />
    <local:MyClass x:Key="mc2" Data="{StaticResource CData}" />
</Window.Resources>
```

where `local` points to your namespace where both classes are defined.